# No xml output on page

Tags: asp.net, xml, outputstream

I am trying to output xml on my aspx page. But it returns no result.

The aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Sitemap.aspx.cs"
 Inherits="Servicebyen.Presentation.Web.Sitemap" %>
```

The code behinde:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";

    var writer = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);

    writer.Settings.CloseOutput = false;
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("urlset");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
    writer.Flush();
    writer.Close();
    Response.End();
}
```

Can you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "no result"? Do you mean it shows up blank in a browser?  Have you tried getting the content with a command-line tool? What happens if you "view source" inside the browser?  Are you at least getting the right content type header?

Comment: It shows up blank in the browser. When I view source I get:
What should I do?

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type></HEAD>
<BODY></BODY></HTML>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing this out in Google Chrome then you will get a blank page is it doesn't render xml files well from websites.

Another thing to try is rather than implement this as a page implement it as a [Generic Handler](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Generic_Handlers_(ASHX_Files).html). This avoids the overhead of the Page Lifecycle for ASP.NET and reduces the places where errors can occur or mistakes can be made.